# Core Data persistent store coordinator EXC_BAD_ACCESS during migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, core-data-migration

I am performing an upgrade to `Core Data` in our app and am using a `.xcmappingmodel` and Migration Policy. During this upgrade I am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in my `AppDelegate` `persistentStoreCoordinator` method:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];

    // handle db upgrade
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES};

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

[image]

Call Stack (Thread 1 Queue: com.apple.main-thread (serial)):

```
#0  0x00000001053f29f9 in _propertyAtIndexForEntityDescription ()
#1  0x00000001054449e5 in -[_NSFaultingMutableSet description] ()
#2  0x000000010831fdca in -[NSObject(NSObject) _copyDescription] ()
#3  0x00000001083039ab in __CFStringAppendFormatCore ()
#4  0x0000000108337658 in CFStringAppendFormat ()
#5  0x0000000108332125 in -[__NSDictionaryI __apply:context:] ()
#6  0x00000001083a480d in _CFErrorFormatDebugDescriptionAux ()
#7  0x00000001083a4565 in _CFErrorCreateDebugDescription ()
#8  0x00000001078eacf6 in -[NSError description] ()
#9  0x000000010839ad4a in -[NSArray descriptionWithLocale:indent:] ()
#10 0x000000010831fdca in -[NSObject(NSObject) _copyDescription] ()
#11 0x00000001083039ab in __CFStringAppendFormatCore ()
#12 0x0000000108337658 in CFStringAppendFormat ()
#13 0x00000001083a480d in _CFErrorFormatDebugDescriptionAux ()
#14 0x00000001083a4565 in _CFErrorCreateDebugDescription ()
#15 0x00000001078eacf6 in -[NSError description] ()
#16 0x00000001078463d9 in _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc ()
#17 0x0000000108303407 in __CFStringAppendFormatCore ()
#18 0x00000001083008f7 in _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 ()
#19 0x00000001054576d3 in PFLog ()
#20 0x00000001053c316c in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] ()
#21 0x000000010395a630 in ::-[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]() at <redacted path>/AppDelegate.mm:522
#22 0x0000000103959e19 in ::-[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]() at <redacted path>/AppDelegate.mm:469
#23 0x0000000103a7351a in -[ZSSCoreDataManager init] at <redacted path>/ZSSCoreDataManager.m:32
#24 0x0000000103a73432 in __35+[ZSSCoreDataManager sharedService]_block_invoke at <redacted path>/ZSSCoreDataManager.m:20
#25 0x000000010c8940cd in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#26 0x000000010c8791fc in dispatch_once_f ()
#27 0x0000000103a733d8 in _dispatch_once [inlined] at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/once.h:75
#28 0x0000000103a733bd in +[ZSSCoreDataManager sharedService] at <redacted path>/ZSSCoreDataManager.m:19
#29 0x0000000103aa44fe in -[ZSSTabBarController updateSettingsBadgeValue] at <redacted path>/ZSSTabBarController.m:49
#30 0x0000000103aa4381 in -[ZSSTabBarController viewDidLoad] at <redacted path>/ZSSTabBarController.m:28
#31 0x00000001098c906d in -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] ()
#32 0x00000001098c94a0 in -[UIViewController view] ()
#33 0x0000000109793045 in -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] ()
#34 0x0000000109793796 in -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] ()
#35 0x00000001097a70a9 in -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] ()
#36 0x0000000109720259 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] ()
#37 0x00000001097263b9 in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] ()
#38 0x0000000109723539 in -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] ()
#39 0x000000010e67776b in __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#40 0x000000010e6775e4 in -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] ()
#41 0x000000010e67796d in -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] ()
#42 0x000000010836a311 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#43 0x000000010834f59c in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#44 0x000000010834ea86 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#45 0x000000010834e494 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#46 0x0000000109721db6 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#47 0x0000000109727f34 in UIApplicationMain ()
#48 0x0000000103a8addf in main at <redacted path>/main.m:14
#49 0x000000010c8e068d in start ()
```

From what I read elsewhere this is a thread issue. What should I do here? Trying to create the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` on the main thread didn't help.

During a migration, is iOS trying to call this from a background thread? Should I be locking the thread or using `performBlockAndWait:`?

Comment: Can you share the call stack? Is it in a background thread?

Comment: @DaveWeston Just added it.

Comment: It looks like it's crashing while trying to build an error message to return to you, but it's hard to tell exactly what's going on. One thing that you can check is to make sure your model objects all inherit from `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: If you're still stuck with this problem, would it be possible for you to share the project privately?

Comment: @DaveWeston No, I wouldn't be able to share the project privately. But I would be happy to provide more details away from Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure, let's chat. Are you on Telegram?

Comment: @DaveWeston I am not. I will send you a message on Twitter.

Comment: @DaveWeston I just created an account. Username is zedsaid